# DynamicResource with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have `UserControl` which needs to perform some multi-linguality. In constructor, I dynamically load proper XAML with `ResourceDictionary`. In that XAML I have:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<system:String x:Key="somekey">Some Label</system:String></ResourceDictionary>
```

I then have

```
Header = {DynamicResource somekey}
```

in `DataGridTextColumn` in DataTemplate which is also used by this `UserControl`. It looks like the DataTemplate doesn't know about the new ResourceDictionary.

But, it does not work. Please, why?

Comment: Is the ResourceDictionary loaded before the UserControl is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should *bind* the (re)source to the header content. The resource itself cannot notify any change, so the binding may be the solution.

```
Header={Binding Source={DynamicResource someKey}, Path=.}
```

Anyway I'm not sure: never try such a condition.